# How to merge text conversations from multiple numbers into a single one?

Tags: sms

I have a handful of people who have more than two numbers they contact me from, and I find it annoying to have so many different conversations for one person. I'm looking for a way (preferably, an app) that would let me just have one 'conversation' and just change the number.

I had a phone that did this automatically. I'm 99% sure it was a dual-sim phone, so I'm pretty sure it's possible to do.

Answer (score 0):

**To answer your question**

- Open Contacts
- Find Contact A's Name.
- Click Edit and add an addition number to contact A, number Two.
- Click Mobile, Home or Work phone.
- Save the contact with multiple Numbers.

---

**It's all pretty straight forward for an experienced human being... :)**

- Reloading messages should attach the two conversations as one, if not, future conversations will be marked as the same contact.

Comment: This seems to no longer work on current Android versions (i.e. Android 9 / Pie).